# Is the phrase "mutual trust" redundant?

Tags: phrases, redundancy

The phrase is being used in the following sentence:

"Always keep your promises and seek to strengthen mutual trust."

I feel that the sentence would be better with just "trust", but the person who originally wrote this wants it to be clear that the trust is two way.

Comment: Do you think that the phrase "trust each other"—as in "Always keep your promises and seek to strengthen the idea that you and those you interact with can trust each other"— is redundant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Mutual trust* can be used to emphasise the two-way part. For example, a pupil can trust their teacher (just because they are educated grown-ups), but that doesn't mean the teacher trusts the pupil. On the other hand, the pupil can be punctual and keep their promises so that the teacher will begin to trust that pupil over time. In that case, mutual trust is strengthened.

Comment: "I think" is comment, not an answer. The question is POB.

Comment: @Kris Yet it says *answer* at the top. I will remove the *I think* part, seeing it makes people uncomfortable or confused.  There are arguments for saying it redundant and there are arguments against it. Laying out those arguments is still helpful and it would be a mistake to close as POB.

Comment: "Arguments are not answers." <-- And that's not an opinion or an argument. Please read the FAQ.

Comment: @Kris please be more specific. My take on the help centre: [*Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.*](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: "Your take" is an opinion, could even be an argument.

Comment: @Kris my take is actually written in the help centre. If you are citing the FAQ, as you did in an earlier comment, that arguments cannot be answers then you better provide that link to where that rule is written. I should inform you, that comments are not for extended discussion (not my rule) and as such I will not be responding (here) to comments unrelated to my answer.

Comment: This is an excellent answer to a valid question. The criticism is invalid.

Comment: As the original asker, I found that the JJJ's comment was an adequate answer to my question.  I had assumed that in the context of the sentence  "trust" was inherently mutual.  However they demonstrated that trust can be one way as well.